# How do you give tcltk message boxes the top level in R?

Tags: r

Could somebody please tell me how to give a `tcltk' message box top level focus in R?

I have a MWE below. If you run the code and drag the message box you will see that it always goes behind base window (which represents the main window of my application).

```
library(tcltk)

base = tcltk::tktoplevel()
tcltk::tcl("wm", "attributes", base, topmost = TRUE)

loadYN <- tcltk::tkmessageBox(title = "",
                            message = "I really wish I appeared at the top 
level :(",
                            icon = "question", type = "yesno", default = 
"no")
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

EDIT: I have found a workaround (although I still imagine there is a better way). I am merely manipulating the `topmost` argument contained within the `tcl` function to achieve what I need:

```
library(tcltk)

base = tcltk::tktoplevel()
tcltk::tcl("wm", "attributes", base, topmost = TRUE)

# Changing focus of base frame 
tcltk::tcl("wm", "attributes", base, topmost = FALSE)

loadYN <- tcltk::tkmessageBox(title = "",
                            message = "I really wish I appeared at the top 
level :(",
                            icon = "question", type = "yesno", default = 
"no")

# Changing focus of base frame
tcltk::tcl("wm", "attributes", base, topmost = TRUE)
```

This is a workaround that achieves what I need but doesn't answer my original question so still looking for an answer :)